# MySQL error 1064, not sure what I'm doing wrong here

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-error-1064

```
mysql -u username -p database -e deletedata.sql
```

I get ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'deletedata.sql' at line 1

```
DELETE FROM 'table1' WHERE 'column' <= date_sub(current_date, INTERVAL 37 day);
DELETE FROM 'table2' WHERE 'column' <= date_sub(current_date, INTERVAL 37 day);
```

What could I be missing?

Comment: I tried both solutions and got the same errors...perplexing!

Comment: Can you do a "describe 'table1'" from the MySQL console and paste your table schema here (or at least the relevant fields) so we can work directly with what you've got?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-e executes a statement, not a sql file.
What you need:

```
mysql -u user -p pass db
```

and then into the mysql cli:

```
\. deletedata.sql
```

Backslash dot means "source file"

Or you can just pipe it:

```
cat delete.sql | mysql -u user -p pass db
```

Comment: Thanks...the last think you said to try worked so I went back and looked at my syntax and checked the manual for mysql.  This worked for me:
mysql --user=user_name --password=your_password db_name > deletesql.sql

Now one last question...there is no output...is there any way to make this verbose so I can get a confirmation that it deleted my data?  Thanks.

Comment: Nevermind...I guess I should have RTFM first before posting.  --verbose is the flag to be added to the command line.

Answer (score 1):

Single quotes in MySQL denote string constants. You should be using back quotes (`) to escape table / column names (or identifiers in general).

Comment: What specifically didn't work? `DELETE FROM \`table1\` WHERE \`column\` <=  date_sub(current_date, INTERVAL 37 day);` should work just fine. Are you getting the same error as above?

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you're probably getting into trouble with using table identifiers in the FROM clause.  I stole some examples from one of my databases.  So this will fail:

```
DELETE FROM Session s WHERE s.startTime<=date_sub(NOW(),INTERVAL 30 day);
```

Which is really strange because just replacing "DELETE" with "SELECT *" works.

But this will work fine:

```
DELETE FROM Session WHERE startTime<=date_sub(NOW(),INTERVAL 30 day);
DELETE s FROM Session s WHERE s.startTime<=date_sub(NOW(),INTERVAL 30 day);
```

Syntactic oddities.  Fun!  :-D